# Use wildcards to filter attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, product, filter

I have a collection of products and i want to fitler entity_id attribute using wildcards. For example i want to select a specific set of ids like ids that start with 140 and next number is either 0 or 1,.. until 6, and the rest doesn't matter that much. I was thinking if using this :

```
addAttributeToFitler('entity_id',array('like'=>'140[0-6]%'))
```

but it gives me no results. I don't know if follows the same format of like in SQL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
addAttributeToFitler('entity_id',array('regexp'=>'^140[0-6]*'));
```